# Top navigation is hidden

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I don't want the top of the navigation to be hidden when I scroll to the bottom of the page and see the footer.

Below is the state before scrolling.

[image]

Below is a screenshot when scrolling down to the page.
[image]

Here is the code

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-app-bar>header</v-app-bar>
      <div class="d-flex flex-0-1-100">
        <v-navigation-drawer
          border="r"
          permanent
          fixed
          class="pa-1 position-sticky"
          style="max-height: calc(100vh - 64px)"
        >
          <div style="border: 2px solid pink; height: 100%">
            nav bar
            <v-text-field
              v-model.number="contentHeight"
              min="0"
              step="400"
              type="number"
              label="content height (px)"
            />
          </div>
        </v-navigation-drawer>

        <v-main class="bg-grey pl-0">
          Main content
          <div
            :style="{height: contentHeight + 'px'}"
            class="bg-brown-darken-2"
          >
            content ({{contentHeight}}px)
          </div>
        </v-main>
      </div>
      <v-footer border="t">footer</v-footer>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  const contentHeight = ref(1000)
</script>
```

I would appreciate it if you could check the [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

**I have tried the following**

When I remove the "position-sticky" class from the "v-navigation-drawer," the navigation area at the top does not move upwards even when the footer is visible. However, in doing so, the navigation extends horizontally beyond the footer's boundary, as shown in the image below:

[image]

I may not be able to explain it well in English, but as a layout https://pro-bravia.sony.net/en/guides/
I want it to be the same as if I scrolled down to this site

In the application I'm currently developing, if I use the following v-navigation-drawer, the height of the navigation is halved.

```
<client-only>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      permanent
      class="position-sticky"
      :style="{ maxHeight, minWidth }"
      style="
        height: fit-content;
        margin-top: 64px;
      "
      width="250"
    >
      <v-row justify="center">
        <v-expansion-panels :modelValue="panel" :multiple="true">
          <v-expansion-panel
            v-for="(item, i) in matchedNavObject.children"
            :key="i"
          >
            <v-expansion-panel-title>{{ item.title }}</v-expansion-panel-title>

            <v-expansion-panel-text
              v-for="(navItem, j) in item.children"
              :key="j"
            >
              <nuxt-link
                :to="`${baseUrl}${navItem._path}`"
                class="text-decoration-none"
                :class="{
                  active: `${navItem._path}/` === route.path,
                }"
                >{{ navItem.title }}</nuxt-link
              >
            </v-expansion-panel-text>
          </v-expansion-panel>
        </v-expansion-panels>
      </v-row>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </client-only>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by simply reducing the height of the navbar. The Vuetify default is `height: calc(100% - 64px);`, but you can override it to fit content:

```html
<v-navigation-drawer
  class="position-sticky"
  style="max-height: calc(100vh - 64px); height: fit-content;"
>
```

Note that this will still scroll when the navbar content takes up more height than window height minus header and footer height. You could avoid that by reserving space for the footer (i.e. set `max-height: calc(100vh - 128px)` on the nav drawer), but then that space won't be used even if the footer is not visible.

Finally, if nav exceeds the available height and main content takes up less space than that, the navbar will be cut off at the top, so I would add a `margin-top: 64px` to the navigation drawer, just to be safe.

Here is a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNq1VcFu2zAM/RXCl3RYZSdpsYOXFt1tl31B3YNiy4lWWxIkxU0Q+N9HWXZiOUW6YtgliMgnPj5SpJ+P0Q+l4mbHojRaWVarilr2mAmAVcEb4MVDFlGlsqizobUheOwPw5GsqX7cMlowvUrOlhPIRcoragwGK0hZsT24HzInC7KYz0/B+4iCNnxDLZeCFJq+MX32AqylRhoMpLNobFdM11QwYcfGgVRRsgAlDe+CGsvz10N43dhDxRA5tgHUdE+2jG+2NoWcVvkNZttsgcC3e7X/8j0ED8CSW5JLYTGXCaKmesMFsVKlXYTAPeYe1cOXL4wzJOtrkcJS7cHIiheguHidikgH+HHIEAuM/fnZneArzNR+1oa3ggTAXQC8kYnQjL2ybG9JyVlVhC6AhtSyYFUsdvW6a9iYdZoj1oYLxCzda5i6jGUKfffv+exBOWme5NJd0TWrPDf0Pen7BDfYwemFZKL7cwJ7gusK/4++T2tbJfiqxmOHc3sxd+gPBrOmXJxmar0hG80OoCoSTjDArw7nU7r+ki/fZlDE9x/nea4xh7WWb5gv1a9MkOXVVzwU6eZ4DFja1pXrg+I47eeNFgCwMqWUlunzcsL2P3qbu+v/DRvUb0i/Y/s4q2S0evFocs2VBcPszgN5raS2cATNSmih1LKGGW7tmXOiGGMnhXtwSLeu5p0yDwnm3iNw4BCwSjwjckW3kSdDxSr+baTAL8PRxch6h8miFDqLs2ES7pxFW2uVSZMkLwRew8HgjY4Fs4lQdfKEsETvhOU1I4Wsn+7iu/ge1Rs7NsfM1F1HDdMYJItuRzSWl7i0P6TqkR3DYukpehvBcTGO4yJ2goQN00QzgQ10k/Z3kibXxrImrgtpjr3NRIsFr3Brm0mtc9PV+XlI8t80d9FcqBfH2N5GXaJI7W9EL38AtJVdXQ==)

Here is another [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlVc2O2jAQfpVRLoA2Tvan7YEC2r21h157WVaVCQa8JI5lGxYU5d07thPiBKStVA4knhnPfN/85bWKXqRMjgcWTaOZYYXMqWGLpQCYHQmV0r22B7KiarFjdM3ULO0kjcmaHyHLqdbzZbQmm5ydwP6Re/JAHu7vl1Fj6LwJeuRbangpyFrRD6ZaHcCqVBgAnahl1EklUwUVTJhO1AaTlDyALDV37rTh2f4cXtXmnDO06yQABT2RHePbnZlCRvNsjAiPOyDw7Ys8Tb6Hpq3ZhhuSlcIghp6+oGrLBTGlnLrbgbKLeeHu2LOTpEJbtPhkuYZpUa5Z/pvmBwvUCZcRSg+54dKBN+rAghTedgRHsilt6sYcaxkDnwAXgLn+iUdtPe7ZGdV84OmWL2K4ydmiqsD6StwJ6toW/rblUnzukp2C+vnfBXIDM4Z3h9pFzXY8Xysm+sWzv4bJ+1Az4AWABBrPFw4DnLcYIdB+rq+NwpJea3XX7ai8avcgW5ingiLhtp1XW7JV7AwyJ+HQAPxyVr4Dg9h27qZtj1eXpvZ2P9wR7mAkT6MaOyCIslLlB+Khas8EeRy0RHMfxlXVc1XXOB8hcwzfo2q5tCshUCLLTVkaprr5NhjSy+w9/+ZXj18u+D5Lg52ER50pLg1oZg5+NfFClspABYptoIaNKgsY4TobWSUC12aQibm1tNPuSHgLrA7usZ7BY8/AD5fX2EEMVFtm3HChdpwzsTW7GCTa8dME5g33F6XoObHYxhV4I6hjGP9xEzpfwJjf3cVIwjXotLmPReNQT/o421gWiXfeAhh/jWFkhwZGk6SgslFjiqzMBnFL4TJS6ORy9QmBdAOCzQLOajSZeEVTcPfAv1nq64D0ojjyJcC6y+RdlwI/JJW1wy3jFLh2puAkVoalsedltDNG6mmaZmuB13D58aNKBDOpkEX6jGapOgjDC0bWZfH8lDwlX7CbtAnFCdOF62LNFDpZRnEQxvANfgU+DdVYuggPjz5EIyM5XWkb48p3igGPTBFMI7Yyfrz+kdLgWkhroLqiZqPj4qox4TkXez3IdaZdnl9bkP/H2Xmzrt5sxDqOHFAM7W9Eb38BMt2VPA==) with expansion panels in the nav bar

Comment: Thank you for your many answers.
Actually, I tried to incorporate it into the application currently under development based on the contents of the answer, but it did not work.
I will post the test URL under development, so I would appreciate it if you could check it.
https://www2.pt.sony.co.jp/pub/pro-bravia-nuxt/ja/getting-started/installation/

Comment: Oh, when I click on the link, I get "can’t connect to the server at www2.pt.sony.co.jp"

Comment: sorry. I had made it impossible to access without a VPN connection.
I'm sorry that I couldn't tell you in the comment section and added it to the question, but I added the code and image of the current state to the question.

Comment: That works! You have to remove the `v-row`, it screws up vertical alignment and height of the v-expansion-panels. I have added another playground to the answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. Your response was incredibly helpful, and it allowed me to resolve the issue. Your answers have been greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

how about fix code

```
  <v-app-bar>header</v-app-bar>
  <div class="d-flex flex-0-1-100">
    <v-navigation-drawer
      border="r"
      permanent
      app
      fixed
      class="pa-1"
      style="top: 64px; bottom: 50px"
    >
      <div style="border: 2px solid pink; height: 100%">
        nav bar
        <v-text-field
          v-model.number="contentHeight"
          min="0"
          step="400"
          type="number"
          label="content height (px)"
        />
      </div>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-main class="bg-grey ml-0" style="min-height: calc(100vh - 64px)">
      <v-container fluid class="pa-0">
        Main content
        <div
          :style="{height: contentHeight + 'px'}"
          class="bg-brown-darken-2 mb-8"
        >
          content ({{contentHeight}}px)
        </div>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </div>

  <v-footer fixed app border="t" style="width: 100%">footer</v-footer>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but the footer was hidden by the navigation and the main content was not displayed

Comment: i edit full code and how about this

Comment: Sorry for lack of explanation.
Actually, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76918206/positional-relationship-between-footer-and-navigation/76918981?noredirect=1#comment135615260_76918981 This is related to the question here, but the width of the footer is horizontal i want to fill

Answer (score 0):

I've used the wireframe template from the Vuetify documentation and tried to keep it as simple as it can be. Hope this helps:

[Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-app-bar>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="drawer = !drawer" />
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" clipped class="pa-1" permanent>
      <div style="border: 1px solid pink; height: 100%">Navigation</div>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-main>
      <v-card rounded="0" min-height="100vh" class="bg-brown-darken-2 pa-1">
        Main Content
      </v-card>
      <v-footer style="border: 1px solid pink">Footer Content</v-footer>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const drawer = ref(true)
</script>
```

If you want to keep the navigation temporary, add `temporary` attribute to the `v-navigation-drawer` component.